# How do I tell the line number for a node using the Nokogiri reader interface?

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri

I'm trying to write a Nokogiri script that will grep XML for text nodes containing ASCII double-quotes («"»). Since I want a grep-like output I need the line number, and the contents of each line. However, I am unable to see how to tell the line number where the element starts at. Here is my code:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'

ARGV.each do |filename|
    xml_stream = File.open(filename)
    reader = Nokogiri::XML::Reader(xml_stream)
    titles = []
    text = ''
    grab_text = false
    reader.each do |elem|
        if elem.node_type == Nokogiri::XML::Node::TEXT_NODE
            data = elem.value
            lines = data.split(/\n/, -1);

            lines.each_with_index do |line, idx|
                if (line =~ /"/) then
                    STDOUT.printf "%s:%d:%s\n", filename, elem.line()+idx, line
                end
            end
        end
    end
end
```

elem.line() does not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

XML and parsers don't really have a concept of line numbers. You're talking about the physical layout of the file.

You can play a game with the parser using accessors looking for text nodes containing linefeeds and/or carriage returns but that can be thrown off because XML allows nested nodes.

```
require 'nokogiri'

xml =<<EOT_XML
<atag>
  <btag>
    <ctag 
      id="another_node">
      other text
    </ctag>
  </btag>
  <btag>
    <ctag id="another_node2">yet
                             another
                             text</ctag>
    </btag>
  <btag>
    <ctag id="this_node">this text</ctag>
  </btag>
</atag>
EOT_XML

doc = Nokogiri::XML(xml)

# find a particular node via CSS accessor
doc.at('ctag#this_node').text # => "this text"

# count how many "lines" there are in the document
doc.search('*/text()').select{ |t| t.text[/[\r\n]/] }.size # => 12

# walk the nodes looking for a particular string, counting lines as you go
content_at = []
doc.search('*/text()').each do |n|
  content_at << [n.line, n.text] if (n.text['this text'])
end
content_at # => [[14, "this text"]]
```

This works because of the parser's ability to figure out what is a text node and cleanly return it, without relying on regex or text matches.

---

EDIT: I went through some old code, snooped around in Nokogiri's docs some, and came up with the above edited changes. It's working correctly, including working with some pathological cases. Nokogiri FTW!

Comment: Well, I'm trying to output something like grep -n's output that I can easily input into Vim. And, BTW, CPAN's XML-Parser which I tried next, was able to tell me the physical line in the file's text in which a text node starts at so I could calculate the occurence of the double-quotes using a split. And this finally worked. So I'm a bit unhappy with your answer and assume this is a Nokogiri deficiency.

Comment: If you don't like an answer, you should not accept it. Nokogiri uses libXML2 as its engine, which is an industry standard parser, so I hardly think a fault lies with Nokogiri. I haven't used Perl's XML-Parser in years. It could be using Expat, which is an older parser, or it could be using libXML2 or it could be doing it all in Perl. However it's doing it, it is still subject to the same issues and can get things wrong the same way.

Comment: @Shlomi Fish, take a look at the edited code. It is succinct and handles conditions I thought would throw off Nokogiri. I switched from the Hpricot XML parser years ago to use Nokogiri exclusively, and once again it showed me how good it was.

Answer (score 0):

As of 1.2.0 (released 2009-02-22), Nokogiri supports [Node#line](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri%2FXML%2FNode:line), which returns the line number in the source where that node is defined.

It appears to use the libxml2 function [xmlGetLineNo()](http://www.xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-tree.html#xmlGetLineNo).

```rb
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::XML(open 'tmpfile.xml')

doc.xpath('//xmlns:package[@arch="x86_64"]').each do |node|
    puts '%4d %s' % [node.line, node['name']]
end
```

**NOTE** if you are working with large xml files (> 65535 lines), be sure to use Nokogiri 1.13.0 or newer (released 2022-01-06), or your `Node#line` results will not be accurate for large line numbers. See [PR 2309](https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/pull/2309) for an explanation.